# How can I reduce the redundancy of this code, so one function can perform the task of printing on Serial and Softserial?

Tags: serial, programming, softwareserial

```
void Multi_print (String str)
{
  Serial.print(str);
  mySerial.print(str);
 }

void Multi_println (String str)
{
 Serial.println(str);
 mySerial.println(str);
}

void Multi_parse_int (int value)
 {
    Serial.print(value);
    mySerial.print(value);
 }
```

Comment: I can't tell what your goal is: One function to replace all three? The same three functions but printing on any one Serial instead of on both ones? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just send your data to a tee: this is a type of pipe fitting where you
push the data through one end and it goes out through the other two
ends. As it happens, both Serial and Softserial (and almost anything
that can `print()`) inherit from the virtual `Print` class. You can
implement a tee as a `Print` that outputs to two `Print`s:

```c++
class Tee : public Print
{
public:
    Tee(Print &_p1, Print &_p2)
    : p1(_p1), p2(_p2)
    {}

    size_t write(uint8_t c)
    {
        size_t count1 = p1.write(c);
        size_t count2 = p2.write(c);
        return min(count1, count2);
    }
private:
    Print &p1, &p2;
};
```

The `write(uint8_t)` is the only method you really need to implement to
have a working `Print`. Then, all the `print()` and `println()` methods
will work.

Example usage:

```c++
Tee dualSerial(Serial, mySerial);
dualSerial.print("The answer is ");
dualSerial.println(42);
```

Note that `parseInt()` will not work, as it is not a method from
`Print`. But if you think twice, you will realize that `parseInt()` on a
pair of channels just does not make sense.

Comment: Very nice solution to the question as asked. :)

Answer (score 1):

LOL, while Edgar was busy answering your question, I posted a github implementation called [NeoTee](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoTee) which will tee any number of streams.  I have occasionally wanted such a class (attached at the end).  He has explained the approach nicely.

One quirk of the Arduino `Print` and `Stream` classes is that the `flush` method is in `Stream`, not `Print`.  So to provide that method in the `NeoTee` class requires deriving from `Stream`.  But `Stream` requires that you implement `read`, `available` and `peek`.  Although `available` can return the sum of the characters available on all `Streams`, the usefulness of `read` and `peek` is functional, but dubious.  ;-)

One example sketch is available in the library.  For your sketch, you would declare something like this:

```
Stream *streams[2] = { &Serial, &mySerial };
NeoTee tee( streams, sizeof(streams)/sizeof(streams[0]) );
```

And used thusly:

```
tee.print( '!' ); // prints one character to both
tee.print( 123.45 ); // prints a floating-point number on both
```

---

NeoTee implementation:

```
#ifndef _NEOTEE_H_
#define _NEOTEE_H_

//------------------------------------------------------
// NeoTee
// Copyright (C) 2016, SlashDevin
//
// This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
// modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
// License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
// version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
//
// This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
// Lesser General Public License for more details.
//

#include <Stream.h>

// This library is like the UNIX "tee" command, which splits an output stream 
// into two streams, but with N branches.  On the Arduino, an output stream is
// instance of the Arduino Print class, and the flush method is in Stream.
//
// Simply declare your own array of streams:
//
//     Stream *streams[2];
//
// Pass the array and its size in to the NeoTee constructor:
//
//     NeoTee tee( streams, sizeof(streams)/sizeof(streams[0]) );
//
// Any Stream operation on "tee" will be duplicated on all Streams in the array.
//
//     tee.println( F("This is sent to all Stream instances in the array.") );
//
// Because there is no base class with "begin" and "end" methods, you
//   must call those explicitly on the individual Streams (e.g., Serial.begin)

class NeoTee : public Stream
{
  Stream **Streams;
  uint8_t  NumStreams;

public:

  NeoTee( Stream **streams, uint8_t numStreams )
    {
      Streams    = streams;
      NumStreams = numStreams;
    }

  virtual void flush()
    {
      for (uint8_t i=0; i<NumStreams; i++)
        Streams[i]->flush();
    }

  virtual size_t write(uint8_t c)
    {
      size_t minWritten = 0;
      for (uint8_t i=0; i<NumStreams; i++) {
        size_t written = Streams[i]->write( c );
        if ((i == 0) || (minWritten > written))
          minWritten = written;
      }
      return minWritten;
    }

  using Stream::write; // make the other overloads visible

  virtual int available()
    {
      int total = 0;
      for (uint8_t i=0; i<NumStreams; i++)
        total += Streams[i]->available();
      return total;
    }

  virtual int read()
    {
      for (uint8_t i=0; i<NumStreams; i++)
        if (Streams[i]->available())
          return Streams[i]->read();
      return -1;
    }

  virtual int peek()
    {
      for (uint8_t i=0; i<NumStreams; i++)
        if (Streams[i]->available())
          return Streams[i]->peek();
      return -1;
    }

};

#endif
```

Comment: Very nice solution to the more general problem. :)